# msvcr100d.dll missing from computer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have tried the basic update as suggested by many, the SP 1 redistribute for 2010 VS x86. I have also tried the sp for 2012 and 2013. I have VS 2013 and Windows 7. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

msvcr100d.dll is the debug version of the DLL and should be installed when you install Visual Studio 2010 and cannot be legally redistributed (so isn't part of the redistributable packages).

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting the wrong runtime. Your program targets the debug runtime. Which is why when you take it to another machine, the runtime cannot be found, even if you have installed the redistributable. Remember that the debug runtime cannot be redistributed and naturally is not part of the redistributable.

Rebuild your program against the release runtime and all will be well.

Comment: I'm running from cmd prompt. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: It does not matter how you run the program. You simply have to link against the correct runtime. Since the debug runtime cannot be redistributed, if you want your program to work on a machine that does not have VS installed, you need to link against the release runtime.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm not very familiar with this type of problem.

Comment: Switch the Configuration drop down in VS from Debug to Release.